# Firebase authentication link whitelist exception (sendSignInLinkToEmail)

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

We've been successfully using passwordless authentication for the last half year on a web app hosted on Firebase's hosting:

```
AngularFireAuth.auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail
```

Yesterday afternoon, we all of a sudden start seeing "Domain not whitelisted by project" exceptions when sending the link. The domain is and has been whitelisted all this time. The actual message is:

> Xr {code: "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri", message: "Domain not
>   whitelisted by project"}

Customers are completely locked out of their accounts and I have no idea how to fix this.

Help!!!

Comment: If there's no code change, it's unlikely anyone here can help. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Firebase support.

Comment: Reached out to start a ticket. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it but am still not sure exactly how I got into this situation. I read a post that indicated a sha key problem caused the same error message for someone after updating some tools. So I:

1. Removed, cleaned, and reinstalled angular (as well as all other tools)
2. Rolled back my (very innocuous) code changes
3. Built and re-deployed and it was fine.
4. Re-introduced my code changes, built and re-deployed and that was fine

Wish I knew exactly what I did to get there, but at least I found a way out.